# How do I find My Computer in Unity?

Tags: unity, nautilus

There seems to be no option for My Computer, could anyone tell me how to find it?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you can't find your computer, what are you using to visit this site? On a serious note though, can you clarify your question?

Comment: Ryan, did you mean the equivalent of Windows' "My Computer"?

Comment: Yeah sorry guys, I'm after the equivalent of windows my computer.

Answer (score 5):

Open the file browser, then mouse over the bar at the very top of the screen so that the menu bar becomes visible. Click on *Go* and then click on *Computer*. (i.e Menubar ⟶ Go ⟶ Computer)

[image]

To make it easier to access Computer in the future, add a bookmark. Press <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+ <kbd>D</kbd> and you will now see *Computer* listed in the bookmarks on the left of the file browser window:

[image]

Once bookmarked, you can directly access Computer by right clicking the file browser icon in the dash:

[image]

You can bookmark almost any location in this way for easy access.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to 'File System' you are in the so called root directory of your ubuntu installation.

The folder 'home' points to your user home folder with all your data (music, photos, docs etc.) in it.

The 'media' folder is where any mounted devices will show up (iPods, USB sticks, additional HDDs, DVD etc.) you can also find these in the devices section of the file manager in the top left corner.

The 'usr' folder contains information and the executables to all the programs you have installed through the software center as well as some settings.

If you're new I wouldn't bother about the other folders for now cause they contain data that's crucial to your system.

You can't do anything outside of the '/home/your_username folder' without root privileges.
To get them you can press Alt+F2 and type 'gksu nautilus'.

But if you're new to linux and don't really know what you are doing I'd strongly recommend you don't use it because you could mess up your install beyond repair.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file browser (the second from top in the column on the left hand side of the screen).

Look in the left column of the window that opens. One of the options is called "File System" - this is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

### 12.04 with nautilus 3.4.2:

There is a nice patch for Ubuntu 12.04 with nautilus 3.4.2. This patch will create a nice toolbar-like icon set for several activity, such as *refresh*, *up*, *Computer* etc.

1. Download the patch from [lauchpad page](https://launchpad.net/nautiluspatchtogglelocationbar/+download). Download and save the .deb file in your *Downloads* folder

   - [32bit deb file](https://launchpad.net/nautiluspatchtogglelocationbar/trunk/nautiluspatchtogglelocationbar/+download/nautiluspatch_v3.4.2-0ubuntu3-2_i386.deb), if you are using 32bit Ubuntu or
   - [64bit deb file](https://launchpad.net/nautiluspatchtogglelocationbar/trunk/nautiluspatchtogglelocationbar/+download/nautiluspatch_v3.4.2-0ubuntu3-2_amd64.deb), if you are using 64bit Ubuntu.
2. Now open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut and use the command to install it.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/nautiluspatch_v3.4.2-0ubuntu3-2_i386.deb
   ```

   for 32bit or

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/nautiluspatch_v3.4.2-0ubuntu3-2_amd64.deb
   ```

   for 64bit.
3. Now restart nautilus by using `nautilus -q` command and then clicking  the home icon in dash
4. Now, in nautilus menu , Go to *Edit* → *Preferences*. In the *File management Preferences* window, select the new ***toolbar*** tab.
5. Now check the corresponding checkbox to enable the button.

   [image: nautilus preference window]

   the added are buttons are

   [image] 
   Now you can have a My computer view like this

   [image: my computer view]

We hope this patch will continue to be alive for future nautilus versions

Answer (score 0):

Download Advanced setting from ubuntu software center and at desktop tab you can show mycomputer icon and also trash icon.